# APNS doesn't call didReceiveRemoteNotification after icon click

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I m tring to pass the below payload from PHP Server to APNS.

```
$body['aps'] = array(
        'badge' => 1,
        'ArmyGroupID' => 12345
);
```

While the app in the foreground, i get the entire dictionary, that is no issue.

**Problem:**

But while the application is in the background, it successfully appends the badge,
but while I click on the icon, the message is not dispatched to didReceiveRemoteNotification.

Am I doing it in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour.See following snippet from Apple documentation:

> As a result of the presented notification, the user taps the action button of the alert or taps (or clicks) the application icon.
>   If the action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system launches the application and the application calls its delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it passes in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the local-notification object (for local notifications).
>   **If the application icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the application calls the same method, but furnishes no information about the notification** . If the application icon is clicked on a computer running OS X, the application calls the delegate’s applicationDidFinishLaunching: method in which the delegate can obtain the remote-notification payload.

As a workaround I can suggest one little check into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Get user info dict
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [launchOptions   valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber >0 && userInfo == nil){
        //Do like you did in didRecieveRemoteNotification method
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You actually want to check `userInfo != nil`. I also suggest the use of the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` constant instead of an error-prone static string.

Comment: I'm agree for constant, but not agree about userInfo check.In question is said, that he clicks icon, and when click icon userInfo is nil.If alert of push notification is clicked then userInfo is not nil.

Comment: Not really. He said that the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is not called and that's why the notification should also be searched for in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as you pointed out. How would you handle a nil notification anyway?

Answer (score 0):

in swift2:

```js
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  }
```